# Prioritizing port 80 on a shared network

Tags: networking, ports

I share my internet connection with my entire town of about 1000 people.
This makes the connection very slow when trying to browse the web (youtube videos takes forever to load on 144p).
When downloading torrents though, download speed is fairly reasonable (400 kbytes/s). Could it be that priority for the ports is that way, or that the torrent software is more persistent with requiring bandwidth?

How could I prioritize port 80? Is there a way (or workaround) to do this without admin priviliges?

Comment: What is the connection speed, what router are you using and how are you distributing access to everyone?

Comment: Yes could you add the Equipment used in this setup it would be interesting. If you know anyways. When you do a speedtest what kind or results does it give you?